# Terraform - Remove AWS security_group_rule from a PostgreSQL DB after upload of dump has been completed

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

I got a Terraform script in which I setup a PostgreSQL DB in AWS.

There my idea was to:

- Setup the DB with a security group which got port 5432 closed
- Add a rule to the security group which opens port 5432 to the internet
- Upload the DB schema and some initial data from a linux machine
- Close the port 5432 again - later I want to change this to be only reachable from a Lambda function...

So I got this Terraform code in one script which I execute with "terraform apply":

```
// Setup the DB with a security group which got port 5432 closed 1/2
resource "aws_security_group" "PostgreSQL-SecGrp" {
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.default.id}"
  name        = "PostgreSQL-sec-group"
  description = "Lock traffic from outside"
}

// Setup the DB with a security group which got port 5432 closed 2/2
resource "aws_db_instance" "app_rds" {
  identifier             = "mypostgresqldb"
  db_name                = "PostgreSQLDB"
  instance_class         = "db.t2.micro"
  allocated_storage      = 5
  engine                 = "postgres"
  engine_version         = "12.7"
  skip_final_snapshot    = true
  publicly_accessible    = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.PostgreSQL-SecGrp.id]
  username               = "user"
  password               = "<secretPassword>"
}

// Add a rule to the security group which opens port 5432 to the internet
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "open_port5432" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.PostgreSQL-SecGrp.id
  
  type = "ingress"
  from_port   = 5432
  to_port     = 5432
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  
}
    
// Upload the DB schema and some initial data from a linux machine (1/2)
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.6"
 required_providers {
   ssh = {
      source = "loafoe/ssh"
    }
  }
}

// Upload the DB schema and some initial data from a linux machine (2/2)
resource "ssh_resource" "init" {

  host         = "<linuxMachine>"
  user         = "..."
  password     = "..."
  
  commands = [
  < command to upload a psql dump into postgresql >
  ]
}

// Close the port 5432 again
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "close_port5432" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.PostgreSQL-SecGrp.id 
  <????>
}
```

Everything works apart from the last point which shall remove the acessibility from the internet again - because it did not remove/change the security group again. My supposition was that I have maybe to import the created security group again and then modify its resource anyhow, but also there I didn't find anything usefull.

Does anybody got an idea how to do this? Or, since this also looks a bit like a standard problem to me (setup a DB, inject some initial data and then locking it from the internet), maybe someone could point me to a documentation, in which it is described to setup something like this?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to pass a variable to Terraform and use the value of that variable in your Terraform templates to determine what should be deployed. For example if you have an [input variable](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables) defined like this:

```
variable "public_db" {
  type    = bool
  default = false

  description = "Expose the database to the public Internet"
}
```

Then in your template you could have:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "open_port5432" {
  # We want 1 instance of this rule if public_db is true. 
  # Otherwise we want 0 instances of this rule.
  count = var.public_db ? 1 : 0

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.PostgreSQL-SecGrp.id
  
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 5432
  to_port     = 5432
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

Now when you run `terraform apply -var="public_db=true"` Terraform will create the security group rule, if it doesn't already exist. And if you run `terraform apply -var="public_db=false"` or just `terraform apply"` the security group rule will be deleted (if it exists).

Comment: Thanks Mark and v-rosa, this is a good idea. 
Sooo....... in order to get this done in one "terraform apply" I would:
 --> shift this resource into an own tf module
 --> import this module in main "main tf script", once with an input variable set to "1" for adding the ports
 --> upload the sql dump
 --> import this module a second time with the input variable set to "0" for not adding this group

If this how you suggest to do it?

Comment: No. That's not how Terraform works at all. Terraform is not procedural, it is imperative. Terraform takes all your templates and determines a specific state that you want your infrastructure to be in, and then it makes that happen. You can't have terraform create something, and then later delete something all in the same action. There is no way to get Terraform to create something, wait a bit, and then delete that thing all in a single `terraform apply`. If you need to do this all in a single "command" then wrap it in a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the initial security group rule `open_port5432`, and perform a terraform plan and apply.

You could also use count as a feature flag to enable/disable the needed security groups.

```
count = local.enable_external_access ? 1 : 0
```

NB: it's a bad idea to expose your instance to 0.0.0.0/0 I would like to suggest if possible to use the specific external IP using /32 which will bootstrap the DB. Or use a lambda to do so, this way you only expose your DB in the private network.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on the feedback of Mark and v-rosa, I want to come up with a solution which seems to work.

At first the overall security group of my code snipped (see the top of this thread):

```
resource "aws_security_group" "PostgreSQL-SecGrp" {
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.default.id}"
  name        = "PostgreSQL-sec-group"
  description = "Lock traffic from outside"
}
```

stays in the top level main.tf file.

Then I use the hints from Mark and v-rosa and shift the security group rule into an own tf file, in an own folder:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "everything_around_port_5432" {
  security_group_id = ...
  count = var.public_db ? 1 : 0
  type = "ingress"
  from_port   = 5432
  to_port     = 5432
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  
}
```

Then back in the "top level" main.tf I added two null_ressources:

```
resource "null_resource" "create_rule_with_open_port" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = "./postgres_db"
    command     = "terraform init"
    interpreter = ["cmd", "/C"]
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = "./postgres_db"
    command     = "terraform apply -auto-approve -var=public_db=true"
    interpreter = ["cmd", "/C"]
  }
}

/*
At this point the database is running and the port is open. 
Do the dump upload with:
*/

resource "ssh_resource" "init" {

  host         = "<linuxMachine>"
  user         = "..."
  password     = "..."
  
  commands = [
  < command to upload a psql dump into postgresql >
  ]
}

# ... and then proceed with the removal of the port again.

resource "null_resource" "remove_rule_again" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = "./postgres_db"
    command     = "terraform apply -auto-approve -var=public_db=false"
    interpreter = ["cmd", "/C"]
  }
  depends_on = [ null_resource.create_rule_with_open_port, ssh_resource.init ]
}
```

When I now run "terraform apply" on the top level file it calls this new tf file which is in charge for the security_group_rule and sets the port - and removes it again.

Probably the script can be tuned to e. g. not always do the "terraform init" in the first place.

And a small side note: This new tf file also gets an own state file and I was a bit wondering if this can get messed up when I call "terraform destroy" on the top level script. However when I call "terraform apply" on the top level script, in the specific state file is one resource added - and removed again. So this state is "empty" - that's my theory.

Comment: You don't need a module unless you want to re-use this terraform code in other environments for example. See [HCP documentation about when to create modules](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop#when-to-write-a-module). For now, following Mark's suggestion you just need to add a file named variables.tf in the working directory, add the suggested variable and adjust your code like Mark pointed.

Comment: Hi V-Rosa, yes but then I would need to call my main.tf file twice (once with public_db=true and once with public_db=false). What I wanted to implement is that this is entire process is hidden behind one "terraform apply". And with my solution I got this, because my call "terraform apply" on my main.tf file triggers these internal calls on this new tf-file for the security_group_rules.

Comment: See my reply to your comment on my answer. There is no way to have Terraform create something, and then later delete that same thing in a single `terraform apply` Terraform is not a scripting language. It's really unclear why you even need all this to happen in a single `terraform apply` but it's not possible anyway. Wrap it in a shell script that calls `terraform apply` twice if you need it to all happen in a single command.

Comment: Hi both. Ok, technically my solution is able to do what I described: I got a terraform script which is sets up some resources in AWS and then calls another TF script to once set a resource and then later remove it again. But I was carefully reading your comments and I think we are also heading to a section what should be done instead of what can be done. So apparently using TF in a way as I described is not a good practice and instead I should manage this in a shell script. Since I am still learning terraform this is a good information for me and I will consider this.